# How to set login page as main path in an AD Federation server?

Tags: windows, server, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, federation

When my users are using the AD Federation single sign on server, they must go to the full path of the login. Ex: https://login.example.com/adfs/fs/SingleSignOn.aspx

Instead I am wanting them to connect to https://login.example.com, which I am wanting to be the directory for the login page. I could either move the login path to be the index file for the subdomain, or I could simply have https://login.example.com/ redirect to https://login.example.com/adfs/fs/SingleSignOn.aspx.

Is this possible to do in any way only using AD Federation? I know using IIS would be a simple solution, but these machines are not supposed to be running IIS or anything similar.

I am very new to using AD Federation and have very limited experience, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this with ADFS out of the box. You will need to put a proxy infront of ADFS with a rewrite rule. As you already guessed, this should not be run on the same server as ADFS, as they should never be directly exposed to the internet. It is recommend, at the minimum, to use a web application proxy anyway.